# Anyone know an actor that played an admiral on Star Trek that was also a CFO for Shelby Cars?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I know this is a stretch, but I'm looking for the name of an actor that was a board member of the *Shelby American Car Company* during it's heyday. He then retired and went on to acting, most notably as one of Star Trek's Admirals, I think on TNG.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Shelby :D

Comment: Her name was Shelby. I'm thinking of a guy.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to IMDB every episode and then Google every actor playing an admiral.  (Assuming that IMDB list the character as "Admiral Halsey" rather than just first and last name.)

Comment: Well, here's a link to Memory Alpha's list of Starfleet Admirals.  http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_flag_officers

Comment: This would be very difficult to answer unless the actor in question put "former board member of Shelby" in their bio which may be unlikely. I think your best bet would be to contact Shelby and hope someone is willing to put together a list of former board members that you can then cross reference.

Comment: @Emsley Wyatt. Shoot. I went through all those and didn't find who I was looking for. Thanks for the URL though.

Answer (score 8):

I randomly came up on this - I'm pretty sure you're talking about my grandpa!

> [image]
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: The Next Generation* - S05E01 - "[Redemption II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Redemption_II_(episode))"</sub>

Here he is with Carrol Shelby. He was their financial controller originally, then began driving for him later on.

> [image]

---

> We are excited to announce that actor Hal Donahue will be speaking at
> our 20th Anniversary Celebration, August 12! Hal appeared in more than
> a dozen episodes of Star Trek: The Next Generation, is a former Shelby
> Automobile racer, and is actively involved in the American Legion Post
> 143, based in Post Falls, Idaho.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/USSCrusader/photos/a.10151991051295599.893575.214703720598/10158520464380599/?type=3&theater)</sup></sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You forgot to state the _name_ of the actor, though; that's the specific information the OP was asking for. It'd also help if you could provide some evidence that this person was indeed a CFO for Shelby Cars.

Comment: Looks like the first image is from the _TNG_ episode, "[Redemption II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Redemption_II_(episode))," and according to the Memory Alpha page for that episode, the male rear admiral in the image is an unnamed character played by [Hal Donahue](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hal_Donahue).

Comment: @LogicDictates - I've found some evidence that he raced for Shelby; https://cdapress.com/news/2020/may/24/model-behavior-5/. I can't see anything that says that he worked for them in an office role

Comment: @LogicDictates - I've found a 'Hal Donahue' from Montana State University that [graduated in the early 1950s](https://archive.org/details/1962SentinelRed/mode/2up?view=theater). This tracks with him [entering the military in 1953](https://www.spokesman.com/stories/2022/nov/10/ears-to-the-sea-cold-war-veteran-honored-by-city-o/) https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjXD.png but also that he worked as an accountant.

Comment: Being an accountant jibes with being a financial controller which is probably the equivalent to what we'd now call a CFO. This makes sense, but sure could use some more supporting info.